# Short story where two aliens were having a philosophical argument regarding humans, and they develop a rift as a result of the argument

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Ι read this short story many years ago as it was briefly popular on the web at that time.

Τhe short story involves two aliens who were described as large and Ι think, immobile.  Τhey are observing humans from orbit when something like a philosophical disagreement occurs regarding the humans. Τhe story ends as they leave, implying a newfound rift between the forever-changed aliens.

Comment: How many years is many years? Was it 10? or 50? Was it only available on the internet or did it appear in print? Take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872)

Answer (score 3):

You may be thinking of [Gordon R. Dickson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gordon_R._Dickson)'s novelette ["The Odd Ones"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?63170), which is the answer to the question [Duo of alien xenologists study couple of Terran explorers, later save them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188129/duo-of-alien-xenologists-study-couple-of-terran-explorers-later-save-them); first published in [*If*, February 1955](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58725+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/1955-02_IF#page/n7/mode/2up).

The viewpoint characters are two aliens of different species, "philosophical engineers", described as somewhat large (but *not* immobile):

> > The Snorap strongly resembled a very fat and sleepy lizard about ten feet in length—a sort of unterrifying, overstuffed dragon of the kind who would prefer a pleasant nap in a soft chair to eating maidens, any day in the week. His hide was heavy and dark and ridged like armor-plating.
> >
> > The Lut, on the other hand, was built more on the model of an Earthly tiger, except that he was longer—being fully as long as the Snorap—and thicker, with an almost perfectly round body, rather like a big sewer main. He was tailless, his head was big and flat of face, and he possessed an enormous jaw which could crunch boulders like hard candy. His eyes had a fierce green glint to them and he was covered with very fine, but incredibly tough, small glassy scales which would have permitted him to take an acid shower every morning and never notice it at all. But in spite of his appearance, he was just as civilized, just as intelligent, and just as much a gentleman as the Snorap, which put them both, as a matter of fact, several notches above the two humans they were watching, in all those respects.

They observe the human couple, surreptitiously from a distance (*not* from orbit) for most of the story, though they introduce themselves at the end:

> > These two, the Snorap and the Lut, had discovered this world they were on to be a new one, not heretofore checked, and they had just spent the last eighty years or so in going over it. There own ship—which was more of a space-sled than a ship, being completely open, except for an energy shield for meteor protection—was clear on the other side of the planet, they having wandered away from it completely in the past half-century of philosophy-testing. Now they had just stumbled on a pair of human immigrants. These soft little bipeds were a new experience to the Snorap and the Lut, neither of their races having encountered the type before; and they sat in the obscurity of the vegetation that hemmed the little clearing where the human ship had landed, conversing in something that was not verbal speech, sign language, nor telepathy, but a mixture of all three—and they marveled.

The two aliens do have a philosophical disagreement regarding the humans:

> "I might point out," said the Lut, "that, to migrate to a world like this when you are like that, takes a certain amount of moral fiber."
>
> "Ah, but there we come to another question," persisted the Snorap, interlocking the big, blunt claws of his forepaws together like a pedantic old man. "What reason can they have for coming here? They show no intellectual interest in the planet. Their senses are obviously very limited. They seem to have no purpose in being here other than to exist."
>
> "Under great difficulties," said the Lut.
>
> "Granted," answered the Snorap, "under great difficulties. Which merely confirms my belief in their unbalance."
>
> The Lut was by nature a contrary creature, and in addition he was always snappish after a nap.
>
> "And I," he retorted, "prefer to assume that there may be some good reason which you and I are too dull-witted to understand."

The two aliens have a falling out:

> They stood looking at each other.
>
> "I think," said the Lut at last, "I think that we no longer possess the mutual understanding necessary to our partnership."
>
> The Snorap bowed his head.
>
> "I cannot disagree," he said.

But they get over it in the end, after learning more about the humans:

> The Lut crossed over to him and hung his heavy head on the Snorap's shoulder.
>
> "Friend of many years past and yet to come," he said. "We are old fools together."

Answer (score 1):

It makes me think of [They're made out of meat](http://www.terrybisson.com/page6/page6.html), by Terry Bisson, although some details are different.

Two aliens on a contact mission through our sector discuss whether to invite humans to join some sort of galactic federation, but has some trouble accepting our **hideous** biology:

> "It seems harsh, but there is a limit. Do we really want to make
>   contact with meat?"

Really a great short story!

Comment: I thought of that one too, but the whole "They're made out of meat" thing is SO distinctive, I'd think the OP would have recalled it, especially since it's both the title and the "hook".

Comment: Yeah, but memory is so diffuse I thought it didn't hurt

Comment: @user14111 OP states “it was briefly popular **on the web** at that time”. The web did not exist in 1991, so this story is not at all too recent.

Comment: Who knows when or why something gets popular on the web, really!