# Short story where aliens observe new colonists and find out they are male/female

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

A rather old short story... maybe the 70's or 80's... possibly the 90's but I doubt it... that has two aliens sitting on a hill, watching some new aliens arrive (humans). They watch the aliens struggle for a while and cannot figure them out as their behavior seems very strange, and can't decide whether or not to help them.

Eventually one of the aliens has an idea: he figures out that the new aliens reproduce sexually (male/female), that is why they have such bizarre behavior, and so he decides they should help them.

Comment: There's a very similar story I read where some aliens are watching the earth and describing what they think is a religious ceremony but it gradually dawns on the reader that they are describing a football game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Lorendiac for the answer: [Duo of alien xenologists study couple of Terran explorers, later save them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188129/duo-of-alien-xenologists-study-couple-of-terran-explorers-later-save-them?noredirect=1&lq=1)

"The Odd Ones", a novelette by Gordon R. Dickson; first published in If, February 1955, available at the Internet Archive.